# Module must be set dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to create dependencies using dagger 2 with kotlin. I am getting this error on runtime

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: pk.telenorbank.easypaisa.di.modules.RetrofitApiModule must be set
>           at pk.telenorbank.easypaisa.di.DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java:54)
>           at pk.telenorbank.easypaisa.EasypaisaApp.onCreate(EasypaisaApp.kt:22)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1015)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4834)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:168) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5659) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)

Here is dependency graph.

```
@Module(includes = arrayOf(NetworkModule::class))
class RetrofitApiModule(val retrofitMvpApi: RetrofitMvpApi) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMvpApi(): RetrofitMvpApi {
        return retrofitMvpApi
    }
}
```

Here is RetorfitMvpApi

```
@Singleton
class RetrofitMvpApi @Inject constructor(retrofit: Retrofit) : MvpApi {

    var retrofitService: RetrofitService

    init {
        retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService::class.java)
    }

    override fun login(source: String) =
            retrofitService.getPosts(source, Constants.API_KEY)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .map { rs -> rs }
                    .doOnError { t -> t.printStackTrace() }


    interface RetrofitService {
        @POST
        fun getPosts(@Query("sources") source: String,
                     @Query("apiKey") key: String): Observable<WSResponse>
    }
}
```

Here is the component.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, RetrofitApiModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun loginComponent(loginModule: LoginModule) : LoginComponent
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I am using `dagger 2.15`

Comment: post your `DaggerAppComponent` build code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `provideMvpApi` method should take an instance of retrofitMvpApi and return  its interface:

```
@Module(includes = arrayOf(NetworkModule::class))
class RetrofitApiModule() {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMvpApi(val retrofitMvpApi: RetrofitMvpApi): MvpApi {
        return retrofitMvpApi
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, This approach would be even better if you'd use `@Binds` with an abstract class / interface module

Comment: yep, it makes sense. If there's nothing else in this module and it can be made abstract, it'll save the instantiation overhead

Comment: Oh interesting. I'll look into @Binds annotation

Answer (score 2):

Dagger will automatically create `Module` for dependency graph if that `Module` has default constructor. If you use custom constructor then you have to provide the `Module` when you are building the graph.

For java code:

```
@Module
public class ContextModule {

  private final Context context;

  public ContextModule(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
  }

  @Provides
  @GithubApplicationScope
  @ApplicationContext
  public Context provideContext(){
      return context.getApplicationContext();
  }

}
```

Building graph:

```
    githubApplicationComponent = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder()
        .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
        // not needed as Dagger automatically generate module class with no arguments
        //.networkModule(new NetworkModule())
        .build();
```